# Is there a windows tool that allows you to "grab" a window?

Tags: windows, gui, window-manager

On Ubuntu, you can move a window by pressing "Alt" and clicking anywhere inside the window. It's very useful on netbooks, when a big options window can be too large to show the buttons or the title bar.

Is there a tool to do that in Windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a tool that claims to do it :
http://www.hecticgeek.com/2011/11/re-size-and-move-windows-easily-with-altdrag/

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't require a tool: Alt+space will bring up the System Menu of a window, which has a Move entry that grabs the window.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, if a window has a button too far down, I can't use this to show the button on the screen.